# C# decimal to C++ float and javascript number

Tags: javascript, c#, c++

I have a tcp server written in c#. I have to write two client (c++ and javascript). I can deserialize decimal (16byte - 128bit) in c# client but I can't deserialize other languages.

Decimals not too big, I can use float or double.

When serialize decimal:

```
MemoryStream combinedMessage = new MemoryStream();
decimal d = 2135102.06m;
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(combinedMessage, encoding))
{
    writer.Write(d);
}

byte[] message = combinedMessage.ToArray();
```

Serialized as:

```
        62  232 185 12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0
```

How I can deserialize decimal from byte[] in c++ and javascript?

Comment: If you've got to deserialize it as a binary floating point value, why not convert from `decimal` to `float` or `double` first? That should make it much simpler to deserialize in the other languages...

Comment: I can't change server side

Comment: That's unfortunate. In that case you'll need to read the decimal documentation for the precise binary format, and implement the conversion yourself. Basically it'll be a matter of getting the integer out first, then scale appropriately.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://ofwlife.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/c-decimal-wrapper-class/

Comment: @ErikAlapää I tried this already for c++ but this sample doesn't contains byte[] / binary constructor or conversion.

Comment: I guess reading https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs,ee9961220107dcc7,references and http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx should give you an idea how to do it. Reference Sources are hyperlinked by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first 12 bytes are a little-endian 96-bit integer, byte 13 and 14 are unused (for now), byte 15 contains the scale (power of 10 to divide by), and byte 16 contains the sign bit in the MSB (other bits unused). The main difficulty lies in accurate conversion -- even if the decimal is "not too big", converting it to a `float` or `Number` can be done in ways that lose more or less accuracy.

The following routine isn't necessarily the most accurate way to convert decimals, nor the fastest, but if you are not overly concerned with either accuracy or speed it'll get the job done, and it has the benefit of being easy to translate to most any C-like language. Here it is in JavaScript:

```
var b = [ 62, 232, 185, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0 ];

var d = 0.0;
for (var i = 11; i >= 0; --i) {
    var k = b[i];
    for (var j = 0; j != 8; ++j) {
        d *= 2;
        d += (k & 0x80) >> 7;
        k <<= 1;
    }
}
var scale = b[14];
d /= Math.pow(10, scale);
if (b[15] >= 0x80) d = -d;
```

This is almost valid C# already; all you need to change is `Math.Pow` and `byte[] b = { 62 ... }`. For C (and by extension C++) the changes aren't much more complicated:

```
#include <math.h>

unsigned char b[] = { 62, 232, 185, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0 };

double d = 0.0;
for (int i = 11; i >= 0; --i) {
    unsigned char k = b[i];
    for (int j = 0; j != 8; ++j) {
        d *= 2;
        d += (k & 0x80) >> 7;
        k <<= 1;
    }
}
int scale = b[14];
d /= pow(10, scale);
if (b[15] >= 0x80) d = -d;
```

Comment: @CihanT.: I corrected a rather serious bug with the code skipping bytes that were 0 (left over from a previous iteration).